# Exception error in implementing Tower of Hanoi using Linked List

Tags: c++, recursion, linked-list, towers-of-hanoi

I'm trying to implement Tower of Hanoi using Linked List. Here's the code.

```
    struct tower_ {
    int size;
    node* head;
    tower_() {
        size = 0;
        head = NULL;
    }
    int pop() {
        if (size == 0)
            return -1;
        else {
            size--;
            node* iter = head;
            while (iter->next && iter->next->next != NULL)
                iter = iter->next;
            int rt = iter->next->value;
            delete iter->next;
            iter->next = NULL;
            return rt;
        }

    }
    int insert(int x) {
        node* newNode = new node;
        newNode->value = x;
        newNode->next = NULL;
        if (size == MAX_SIZE)
            return -1;
        else if (head == NULL) {
            head = newNode;
            size++;
            return 0;
        }
        else {
            node* iter = head;
            while (iter->next != NULL)
                iter = iter->next;
            iter->next = newNode;
            size++;
            return 0;
        }
    }
    void printTower() {
        node* iter = new node;
        for (iter = head; iter != NULL; iter = iter->next) {
            std::cout << iter->value << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
};

void hanoi(int size, tower_ source, tower_ target, tower_ aux) {
    if (size == 1) {
    target.insert(source.pop());
    return;
}
    hanoi(size - 1, source, aux, target);
    hanoi(size - 1, aux, target, source);
}

int main() {
    tower_ A, B, C;
    A.insert(3);
    A.insert(2);
    A.insert(1);
    std::cout << "A: ";
    A.printTower();
    hanoi(3, A, C, B);
    std::cout << "\n" << "C: ";
    C.printTower();
    return 0;
}
```

When running, I get the following output.

```
A: 3 2 1

C:
```

I don't seem to find any problem with the `pop()` and `insert()` function and I've tested them out separately. I debugged and found out that it might be because of the `-1` return of the `pop()` function for empty list. 
On the other hand, when I changed my hanoi definition to this:

```
void hanoi(int size, tower_ source, tower_ target, tower_ aux) {
    if (size > 0) {
        hanoi(size - 1, source, aux, target);
        target.insert(source.pop());
        hanoi(size - 1, aux, target, source);
    }
```

It throws an exception error at the following line:
`int rt = iter->next->value;` with `Exception thrown: read access violation.
iter->next was nullptr.`

What is the proper way of doing this? Any clue would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at your `pop` function. Now imagine you have a list with `tower::size = 1`. What happens? Namely, what is `int rt = iter->next->value;`?

Comment: Yes. Thank you for pointing it out. Did a little correction on that.
`else if (size == 1) {
   int rt = head->value;
   head = NULL;
   return rt;
  }`
But still C is empty after the operation. Same as before.

Comment: Don’t forget the delete there!

Comment: I did add it. Still, nothing happens.

Comment: Are you trying to write a Towers of Hanoi program in C++ or are you trying to implement a stack using a linked list and solving the Towers of Hanoi is the test requirement? If the former you should use `std::stack`. If the latter you should concentrate on implementing and testing your stack, exercise it with good unit tests that will expose problems. Once you have a well behaved stack, whatever the underlying technique, solving the Towers of Hanoi is trivial. Trying to test your stack with three in use just makes your job more difficult than it needs to be.

Answer (score 0):

A debugger would help. This is what happens when you print out the towers every time they are modified.

```
void hanoi(int size, tower_ source, tower_ target, tower_ aux) {
    if (size == 1) {
        std::cout << "target before insert: ";
        target.printTower() ;
        std::cout << std::endl;
        std::cout << "source before pop: "; 
        source.printTower() ;
        std::cout << std::endl;

        target.insert(source.pop());


        std::cout << "target after insert: ";
        target.printTower() ;
        std::cout << std::endl;
        std::cout << "source after pop: " ;
        source.printTower();
        std::cout << std::endl << "------------------------------------" <<  std::endl;
        return;
    }
    hanoi(size - 1, source, aux, target);
    hanoi(size - 1, aux, target, source);
}
```

---

```
A: 3 2 1 

target before insert: 

source before pop: 3 2 1 

target after insert: 1 

source after pop: 3 2 

------------------------------------
target before insert: 

source before pop: 

target after insert: -1 

source after pop: 

------------------------------------
target before insert: 3 2 

source before pop: 

target after insert: 3 2 -1 

source after pop: 

------------------------------------
target before insert: 

source before pop: 3 2 -1 

target after insert: -1 

source after pop: 3 2 

------------------------------------

C:
```